# "Internal error" when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, sinatra

Whenever I try to push this repo to Heroku, I get this absurdly unhelpful error:

```
Counting objects: 214, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (204/204), done.
Writing objects: 100% (214/214), 196.99 KiB | 306 KiB/s, done.
Total 214 (delta 98), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
       Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-core.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-aggregates.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-postgres-adapter.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-timestamps.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-transactions.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-types.git
       Fetching git://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations.git
       Installing addressable (2.2.8)
       Installing backports (3.3.3)
       Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Installing daemons (1.1.9)
       Installing data_objects (0.10.13)
       Installing descendants_tracker (0.0.1)
       Installing virtus (0.5.5)
       Using dm-core (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-core.git (at master)
       Using dm-aggregates (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-aggregates.git (at master)
       Using dm-do-adapter (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter (at master)
       Using dm-migrations (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations.git (at master)
       Installing do_postgres (0.10.13)
       Using dm-postgres-adapter (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-postgres-adapter.git (at master)
       Installing fastercsv (1.5.5)
       Installing multi_json (1.3.7)
       Using dm-serializer (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer.git (at master)
       Using dm-timestamps (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-timestamps.git (at master)
       Using dm-transactions (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-transactions.git (at master)
       Installing stringex (1.5.1)
       Installing uuidtools (2.1.4)
       Using dm-types (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-types.git (at master)
       Using dm-validations (1.3.0.beta) from git://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations.git (at master)
       Installing eventmachine (1.0.3)
       Installing pg (0.16.0)
       Installing rack (1.5.2)
       Installing rack-protection (1.5.0)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sinatra (1.4.3)
       Installing thin (1.5.1)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
       Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
-----> WARNINGS:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for Ruby/Rack -> console, rake

-----> Compiled slug size: 44.4MB
-----> Launching...
 !     Push rejected, Internal error, please try again

To git@heroku.com:[...].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[...].git'
```

I've tried deleting and recreating the app, deleting and recreating the Gemfile lock, adding a Procfile, and declaring Ruby version '1.9.3' (which I use locally). The app runs without complaint locally. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Pushed the exact same code without modification to Heroku successfully an hour or so later.

This was probably a service problem with Heroku.